# Algorithm for pairing based on preferences and abilities

Tags: algorithm, pairing

Making pairs from two different sets of people based on their preferences and abilities.

One group of people CAN perform both task A and task B, but most of them will only perform task B. In the other group, most of them can only perform task A.

Find an algorithm for pairing up people who can and are willing to perform the same task.

Comment: You cannot use the Gale Shapely algorithm "as is", since it matches elements of two equally sized sets.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the problem can be modelled as an [unweighted matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_general_graphs) problem; two participants will be in an edge if and ony if they share a common language. However this problem is more difficult than the same problem in [bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs), it can be solved within a polynomial runtime bound via an [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) by [Edmonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Edmonds).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the list of all possible couples. If it's correct you could try:

1. Create a list of all debaters with langages ability
2. Create a list with all possible couples of debater with no consideration for langage ability.
3. Filter the previous list by removing incompatible couples.

Steps 2 and 3 can be merged

In python it could be written in functional form with:

```
import itertools as it

# list of debaters as tupple
# [(name, speak english, speak french), ...]
debaters=[
    ('ef1', True, True), ('e2', True, False), ('f3', False, True),
    ('e4', True, False), ('f5', False, True) ]

result=map(
    lambda x: (x[0][0], x[1][0]),
    filter(lambda x: (x[0][1] and x[1][1]) or (x[0][2] and x[1][2]),
           it.combinations(debaters,2)))

print(result)
```

It will print:

```
[('ef1', 'e2'), ('ef1', 'f3'), ('ef1', 'e4'), ('ef1', 'f5'), ('e2', 'e4'), ('f3', 'f5')]
```

You can also write this algorithm with:

```
def compute(d):
    result = list()
    for i in range(len(d)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(d)):
            if (d[i][1] and d[j][1]) or (d[i][2] and d[j][2]):
                result.append((d[i][0], d[j][0]))
    return result
print(compute(debaters))
```